# Error Debugging MVC 4 web application on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am using visual studio 2010 and have installed mvc 4. When debugging using the vs development server the sample web application works perfectly but if i try to debug with IIS i get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.HostAdapters.ASPNETAdapter,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I do not have any references to quality tools in web.config, have tried to add them but still did not work. I also tried o use the aspnet_regiis tool just in case.

i have also tried to target different x64 or x86 platform but it did not make a difference.

My dev machine is windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

You can find an answer [here](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2011/03/18/cannot-start-wcf-web-service-because-of-aspnetadapter-failure.aspx)

> This error is caused by mixed development environment. That means you
>   have build the service with .NET 4 at he x64 machine and somebody else
>   is trying to host the service at his x86 development machine

If it doesn't work, check that the target framework is 4.0

Comment: i am trying to host in on the same physical machine. so iis is 64 bit. I also have tried the to create the same sample app on another 64bit machine and it worked perfectly. the sample apps do not have the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.HostAdapters.ASPNETAdapter, Version=10.0.0.0 referenced as described in the article above, yet on one machine it works on the other it does not. 

Could it be an issue with visual studio itself and should i re-install it?